# why isn't eth (ethereum) working?

Tags: command, line, ethereum

When I run the program 'eth.exe' (from the ethereum frontier website), I am prompted for a password. I enter a password, but then even after several hours I don't get any command line prompt. I simply get a flashing cursor that is still there after hours of time.

[Screenshot for what I get after running eth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Twatc.png)

Operating System: Windows 10
Ethereum blockchain: Downloaded
Other information: Shown in image above.

How do I get to the eth command line interpreter?

Comment: Typing 'eth console' instead of 'eth' gives me a similar result.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the answers for this question: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1652/cant-enter-command-after-starting-eth.

Download the latest binaries from: https://github.com/ethereum/webthree-umbrella/releases
and use

```
 eth --frontier console
```

Comment: Plus one for referencing [Ethereum Stackexchange](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/) :-)

Answer (score 0):

`eth.coinbase` is a command that is used from the ethereum console. Not the command-line, so that definately won't work.  `eth` and `geth` (what I use) are different, so their commands probably different as well.

From [cli installation site](https://www.ethereum.org/cli), try running this: `eth --frontier -b -i`.